# Additional Menu Content in flutter for web apps

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am building a web-app in flutter and for that i have to make a navigation bar in which when mouse is on Navigation item it displays an additional window on top of the original content related to that item and is only active as long as mouse stays on that window or navigation item but i have no idea which widgets to use in this case.

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ytt6Y.jpg)

I have tried to use overlay but it is not working according to my requirement